# Flutter : Get value of pressed numbers in Home widget with number buttons

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I am using this package with customisation [home_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget/example) and trying to build a home widget with number buttons like this image.

[image: this image]

I am trying to achieve it by the following code
My WidgetProvider.kt

```
override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray, widgetData: SharedPreferences) {
        appWidgetIds.forEach { widgetId ->
            val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout).apply {

                // Open App on Widget Click
                val pendingIntent = HomeWidgetLaunchIntent.getActivity(context,
                    MainActivity::class.java)
                setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_root, pendingIntent)

                val counter = widgetData.getString("_number", "")
                Log.i("onMethodCall", "onMethodCall: $counter")
                print("onMethodCall: $counter")
                var counterText = "$counter"

                setTextViewText(R.id.tv_counter, counterText)
                val pendingIntent2 = HomeWidgetLaunchIntent.getActivity(context,
                    MainActivity::class.java)
                setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bt_update, pendingIntent2)

                val backgroundIntent = HomeWidgetBackgroundIntent.getBroadcast(context, Uri.parse("myAppWidget://onNumberBtnClick"))
                setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bt_one, backgroundIntent)
            }
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views)
        }
    }
```

I am passing intent as "onNumberBtnClick" and this is my broadcast function

```
fun getBroadcast(context: Context, uri: Uri? = null): PendingIntent {
        val intent = Intent(context, HomeWidgetBackgroundReceiver::class.java)
        intent.data = uri
        intent.action = HOME_WIDGET_BACKGROUND_ACTION

        var flags = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            flags = flags or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        }

        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, flags)
    }
```

in my "HomeWidgetPlugin" class I have set that value in shared preference.

```
"onNumberBtnClick" -> {
                if (call.hasArgument("id") && call.hasArgument("data")) {
                    Log.i("onMethodCallHere", "onMethodCallHere: ")
                    print("onMethodCallHere")
                    val id = call.argument<String>("id")
                    val data = call.argument<Any>("data")
                    val prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                    if(data != null) {
                        when (data) {
                            is Boolean -> prefs.putBoolean(id, data)
                            is Float -> prefs.putFloat(id, data)
                            is String -> prefs.putString(id, data)
                            is Double -> prefs.putLong(id, java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits(data))
                            is Int -> prefs.putInt(id, data)
                            else -> result.error("-10", "Invalid Type ${data!!::class.java.simpleName}. Supported types are Boolean, Float, String, Double, Long", IllegalArgumentException())
                        }
                    } else {
                        prefs.remove(id);
                    }
                    result.success(prefs.commit())
                }else {
                    result.error("-1", "InvalidArguments saveWidgetData must be called with id and data", IllegalArgumentException())
                }
            }
```

In `main.dart` I handled callback with `workmanager` plugin as in the example of the home widget plugin

```
Future<void> backgroundCallback(Uri? uri) async {
  if (uri?.host == 'onNumberBtnClick') {
    await HomeWidget.getWidgetData<String>('_number', defaultValue: "1").then((value) {
      print("num:$value");
    });
    await HomeWidget.saveWidgetData<String>('_number', "13");
    await HomeWidget.updateWidget(name: 'AppWidgetProvider', iOSName: 'AppWidgetProvider');
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me with what I am missing or how can I achieve this?